# How to display duration (HH:MM) so it isn't confused with clock time

Tags: tables, visual-design, time

I have a table in my application that shows dates along its x-axis, and different statuses along its y-axis.  The table keeps track of how much time an employee spent in a given work status (on duty, off duty, etc) for the given day in hours:minutes.  I've included a rough sketch below:

[image]

My worry is that some users may get confused and think that this time represents something different, such as the time at which this state occurred (i.e. went on duty at 6:00, went off-duty at 18:00).  Is there a better way to represent this time to be more clear of what it is representing, or is this just something that users will have to learn on their own using my software over time?

Comment: What is the resolution of your durations? "4.5h"  would be hard to mistake for half past four, but the numbers are awkward if you need more precision than 15 minutes.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz There are users who cannot comprehend decimal numbers used for this purpose. Some users when presented with a number of hours written as 4.25 will persistently claim it says 4 hours and 25 minutes, regardless of how many times they have been told it is a decimal number and not hours and minutes.

Comment: Simple: Just never display a duration shorter than 24 hours. :)

Comment: @reirab Employees might get a little depressed (and confused) if they see they've been on duty for 25 hours in one day.  Actually... could happen with daylight savings!

Comment: @RhinoFeeder It can also happen when you're crossing time zones, especially if you're traveling from Asia or Oceania to the Americas. I've had 38 hour days before while traveling.

Comment: @kapserd given that it's not uncommon to see times wrongly displayed that way the user doesn't deserve *all* the blame.  But ¼, ½, and ¾ are all available in unicode  and unambiguous.

Comment: How about subdividing the boxes with a faint grey line, so it looks sort of like 4 | 00. You just want to make it slightly different from the very familiar 4:00. Optionally add small headers, h|m || h|m || h|m...

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You are right to ask this question.  It really depends on **who your users are**.

In labor-intensive environments, users are often very familiar with the `HH:MM` notation for duration, so it's OK to use that format.
But, I agree that even for those environments easy to get it confused with time.

**Is there a better way?**

Let's start with the existing solution.  The benefits of `HH:MM` are:

- It's universally recognized as a time format
- It's *scannable*, i.e. when you have lots of data in a grid, the `HH:MM` aligns nicely so it's easy to scan.

With this in mind, here are two approaches.  You could label the existing table to remind users that it's showing duration rather than time.  Or you could adopt a different notation to indicate that it's duration:

[image]

The notation on the left is popular these days, and preserves some (but not all) the scannability while denoting duration more clearly. The approach on the right keeps the cleanliness of the `HH:MM` notation, and sets user context elegantly by utilizing the top-left corner (which is the visual entry-point to the table anyway).

Comment: +1 for the LEFT EXAMPLE. The right one will still cause issues, since people need to figure out there is a label in the upper left hand corner. Users just don't look for content labels there.

Comment: Left example, not the one on the right.

Comment: An advantage of the left approach is that it makes clear that the duration is in fact hours and minutes; saying that the duration of a video presentation is 1:45 may be less clear than saying that it's 1h30m or 1m30s.

Comment: In left example, the hour should stand out more than the minutes.

Comment: I like the left example a ton, and actually can see that being used generally for "duration" throughout the application.  This will train the user well to recognize "hh:mm" as a clock-based time (went on-duty at 3:45), and "xxh xxm" as a duration of time.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder exactly.  As a progressive designer the left example is my preference too.  I felt obligated to include the right hand example because there are many industrial environments where users are accustomed to the `HH:MM` format (e.g. that may be what appears on their time cards or pay slips)...so I'd be remiss to leave it out.

Comment: I like the left solution, however, it has some internationalization issues in [languages that occasionally write *times* in a format like *8h00*](http://www.cscfr.ch/informations/horaires1415pdf/2f3.pdf).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Would adding an `m` fix that?  I think enough languages use "m" for minutes that most people would be able to figure out what "1h23m", "1m23s", and "1h23m45s" meant even if their own language's word for "hours" started with an "S", "o", or some other letter.

Comment: @supercat: I'm not sure, as it's not about those languages' word for "hours" starting with the same letter as the word for "o'clock" in such languages. The issue is that in languages such as French or Spanish, times of the day are literally expressed by saying something like "5 hours 30". Thus, indicating "5 hours" (abbreviated or not) is already ambiguous in these languages to start with, because it may both mean "5 o'clock" or "(a duration of) 5 hours". I am not sure to what extent explicitly adding "minutes" after the minutes number would make any change here.

Comment: @supercat: See, for example, [this example in Portuguese](http://www.cm-viladoconde.pt/PageGen.aspx?WMCM_PaginaId=56853): "Sábado dia 26 de Janeiro, **abertura** do Secretariado no local da prova **das 10h às 12h30m** e das 14h às 18h." (highlight by myself) The bolded part translates to "opening (...) from 10 o'clock till 12:30".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Okay; I knew French used 12h30 as notation for 12:30, but didn't know that some languages also add the "m".  Still, even if "h/m/s" notation doesn't totally eliminate ambiguity with time-of-day in all languages, adding the "m" helps for many, and as noted will allow even German or Spanish speakers to guess that the "m" is minutes (and "h" is presumably the next larger unit, i.e. hours)

Comment: @supercat: Sure, "h" is commonly understood both in Spanish (due to the word for "hours", "horas") and in German (as "Stunde" is commonly abbreviated as "h", "s" already being taken by "Sekunde" ("second"), and "Std." falling out of fashion). If anything, it's the "m" that might be somewhat confusing, as at least in German, minutes are almost always [abbreviated as "min"](http://www.punkt3.de/cms/images/2010-20/05_anzeige.jpg) (to avoid confusion with "m" for "metres").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper as with most internationalization design, it will be case-specific.  If this is an international app, then the real tradeoff is the likely confusion over the `HH:MM` format weighed against the localized confusion over `12h 30m` format.  Locale-specific masks/formats can help.  There is no right or wrong answer here, it will be a reasoned tradeoff informed by proper testing and estimation.  You were right to bring this up for future designers to consider.

Comment: For scanneability I would use CSS pseudo element after or before, to put the `h` and the `m`

Answer (score 26):

A plus sign is sometimes prefixed to the time format indicate offset. It can also imply duration. For example:

```
 +4:00  +10:00  +4:00
 +6:00   +0:00  +6:00
```

Comment: I think that could also be misinterpreted as time zones (e.g. UTC+4), though it is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @Kevin I agree; Even if it may be impossible to actually misinterpret is as time zones without related time - it can easily confuse and unsettle the user, thinking "ok, seems to work like this - but what about the time zones??". To me, looking at it is confusing even now, knowing what it means.

Answer (score 24):

Another possibility would be to add a "prime" mark at the end, as is sometimes (often in race times) used. Minutes and seconds would look like `4′33″`, so a single prime is minutes, so use `1:30′` for an hour and a half.

Comment: I've never seen this used anywhere before.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez this is usually used in races, I believe.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes, but while `4′33″` looks somewhat familiar, `1:30′` does not.

Comment: @Crissov I agree with you that `1:30'` is quite weird. Instead of using a colon, a [degree symbol](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%B0) should be used `1°30'25"`.

Comment: I've only ever seen this used to concisely express a person's height in feet and inches (e.g., I'm 6'2").

Comment: There is a very famous track by composer [John Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Cage) named [4'33"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%B233%E2%80%B3), which refers to its length (4 minutes 33 seconds).

Comment: Yep, the version with degrees is actually valid I think, with the colon just looks plain weird.

Comment: @lxrec: It is used for height, distance, time duration, even angles!

Answer (score 18):

You can also show the minutes with a smaller font.
On stopwatches, this is done for the seconds or milliseconds.

[image]

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faYzD9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I like this answer because it's respectful of the original design intent (to show duration without adding extra digits). It also provides nice visual hierarchy between hours and minutes, which works for many applications. And finally, it elegantly deals with the different heights of the 'h'  and 'm'  which irks me about my own answer :-)

Comment: I agree! This seems to be a good comprimise, and I was surprised at how changing the size of the minutes caused me to recognize the numbers as a duration. I do wonder about readability on a small screen (eg. mobile), but I'm sure that concern could be quashed with testing or more information about how it will be shown.

Answer (score 16):

The international standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) would suggest `P04:00` or `P4H`. Its part on periods, durations or time spans and repetitions, though, is hardly ever followed – and you aren’t using its date format in the first place. JFTR

Please note that `4h00` is not unambiguous, since some people tend to write clock times that way. `4h00m` or `4h00min` would be better.

There‘s also icons: a stop watch ⏱ (with big buttons)  often designates durations (less often an hour glass ⏳) where a clock face  (with big hands) shows times.

Comment: What encoding do those stop watch and clock face glyphs use? they are not displaying correctly in my browser.

Comment: I believe they are from Unicode’s Emoji code block which is outside the BMP, but – unlike many real writing systems – font support should not be that bad nowadays. Anyhow, the stop watch is not showing on every of my current devices either. I think I did not include variation selectors, but have not checked the page source.

Comment: Its probably Chrome. They have lagged behind in emoji support for years. Its finally almost implemented. For me if I select the square and right click the font used in the context menu shows the emoji.

Comment: @Vality Not an encoding problem. If you see no character at all, or an empty square or some such missing character symbol, that means your computer or device has no font containing a glyph for that [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). Usually means the code point is new, a recent addition to Unicode, as is the case for the [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji).

Comment: None of them are working in FF on ubuntu here either -- so can we agree that they're unlikely to be a good idea unless you have 100% control of the user's system? But U+23F1 isn't the emoji block, it's in the [Miscellaneous technical block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Technical#Compact_chart), of which most is supported on my system.

Comment: "Some people" here is for instance people having any French connections. In France, time is written as `15h26` similarly to prices written as `3€99` or `6$25`. However, for timestamp, you'd never write `10h00m` -- that's reserved for time periods.

Comment: @ArturGaspar -1 for standards. Especially ISO may be cool if you write official technical regulations, but is less cool if you communicate data to normal people.

Answer (score 13):

You could use decimals. So for example:

90 minutes would be `1.5 hours` instead of `1:30`

3 hours and 45 minutes would be `3.75` instead of `3:45`

This format is highly scannable and makes it easier to sum the values in your head.

Comment: I absolutely don't agree with this approach! This just confuses the hell ouf of users! Compare 1:55 and 1.916666, what is more readable? I once had to use such a notation, and many people just didn't get it and wrote e.g. 1.40 when they meant 1:40

Comment: @Misch - I think it depends on time increments. I've worked at places that only cared about 15 minute increments. If reporting goes down to the minute then the decimal notation x.xxxx would not be a good solution.

Comment: @Mayo I agree, but in that case I would prefer `<big>1</big> 1/2 h` and `<big>3</big> 3/4 h`.

Answer (score 8):

## ISO 8601 Duration

As mentioned in [the answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/75398/22563) by Crissov, the [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a textual representation of a span of time in this format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`, called [Durations](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601%23Durations).

In this format, the `P` marks the beginning. The `T` separates the days portion from the time (fractional day) portion, and is omitted for whole days.

Examples:

- `P1D` = One whole day.
- `PT5M` = 5 minutes.
- `PT4H30M` means "four and a half hours".
- `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

### Even Briefer: `4H 30M`

You could truncate the `PT` for presentation to the user. So four and a half hours would be: `4H30M`.

Perhaps add a space for readability: `4H 30M`.

[image: example chart using ISO 8601 style presentation of time spans]

### Pros

The upside is that this format is unambiguous, and won't be confused for some other meaning. Another benefit is the fact it is a standard. And the values are somewhat intuitive and easy to read and understand.

### Cons

One downside is that users may not be familiar. So a moment of explanation or training may be needed.

### Programming

Some programming libraries can parse and generate such strings. For Java, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library does so handily with its [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class. Similarly, the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 also offers a [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

Example using Joda-Time 2.7.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
Period period = new Period( now , now.plusHours( 7 ) );
System.out.println( "period: " + period.toString() );
```

Output:

```
period: PT7H
```

Comment: You need more than a moment of explanation or training: you need to persuade your users that you're not crazy. And that's not always easy.

Comment: No, no and no! ISO hyper-super-best-in-the-world-standards _may be_ (not _are_) a good choice for technical reports, regulations etc. But they are the worst choice for communicating things to normal people. The only case when they are a good choice in such case is when they coincide with the notation you chose for another reason.

Comment: @yo' The question asked for ways to display a span-of-time unambiguously. That is the express purpose of ISO 8601, unambiguous textual representations of date-time information. We are not talking about obtuse binary formats. Plain digits and common English letters are used in the suggested format. If you wish to be even more "normal", truncate the `PT` to use `4H30M`. Is explaining "H means hours, M means minutes" really a giant leap of learning?

Comment: @BasilBourque But we're on UX.SE and not engineering.SE.

Comment: @yo' I suggest you re-read the Question. The Question is about situations where being **unambiguous is *more important* than familiarity**. Other Answers suggest inventing a similar notation. My point is simply that there is not need to invent yet another notation. [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) was invented to solve this very problem. I added a screen mockup example. As for "engineering.SE", perhaps such a calmer more rational attitude might be more productive than the thinking that leads to language like "crazy", "No, no, and no!", "hyper-super-best", "worst", "normal".

Answer (score 8):

maybe is out of scope, but scanning a table to detect patrons is not very user-friendly. If resources are available, i would go with an horizontal stacked chart:

[image]

It offers a better perspective of the percentage of time on each status, and is more easy to scan for out-of-patterns days.

Comment: As both a user and a UX developer, I would go with this one

Answer (score 1):

JIRA uses the '3h 15m' style notation which works for me.

Oh the other hand, I used a timesheet system in which time was entered in 15 minute blocks. I found having to enter times as a decimal values like 3.25 was non-intutive way of expressing a duration of 3h 15m.

On the example given, couple of things are not clear:

What is the granularity? Minutes?, 5 minutes or 30 minutes? If showing something like 24 hour days split into several states, I would be thinking along the lines of percentages or segmented bar graphs rather than hours/minutes which might be too precise for a view. Also remember that twice a year you get 23 or 25 hours.

Answer (score 0):

One other solution could be to show the seconds as well.  Since seconds will be changing *quickly* it will be clear that the times are continually changing.  I don't recommend this solution but from the perspective of clarity, it works.

Comment: It does not work to show durations that are no longer changing. (“The machine was used 6:45:21 yesterday.”)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that confusion occurs because there are 2 low-order places with both methods. You could take all the data to fixed 3 decimal places (or 1 decimal place) of an hour, using a decimal point, and rounded before display. Remember to keep the data accurate by doing the maths in integer minutes internally, so minor floating-point errors can't occur when totalling. Another idea is to report everything in minutes.

If you test some alternatives on some users you might be able to get to the best solution, possibly something that hasn't come up yet. Some might think it's your job to resolve the ambiguity.